# Problem in Maximization using genetic algorithm

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, maximize

I was trying to maximize the function `f(x) = x(8-x), x = [0,8]` using this code

```py
import random

def generateChromosome():
    return format(random.getrandbits(8), '0b')

def generatePopulation(size):
    return [str(generateChromosome()) for _ in range (size)]

def fitness(x):
    return x*(8-x)

def decode(x):
    x_int = int(x, 2)
    return 8*x_int/255

def selection(population):
    selected_population = []
    fitness_population = [fitness(decode(chromosome)) for chromosome in population]
    for i in range(len(population) - 1):
        if fitness_population[i] > fitness_population[i+1]:
            selected_population.append(population[i])
        else:
            selected_population.append(population[i+1])

    return selected_population

def crossover(chromosome1, chromosome2):
    new_chromosome = chromosome1[:4] + chromosome2[4:]
    return new_chromosome

def mutation(chromosome):
    random_index = random.randint(1,5)
    try:
        if chromosome[random_index] == '1':
            new_chromosome = chromosome[:random_index] + '0' + chromosome[random_index + 1:]
        else:
            new_chromosome = chromosome[:random_index] + '1' + chromosome[random_index + 1:]
    except:
        new_chromosome = str(generateChromosome())

    return new_chromosome

def offspingGenerator(population):
    offspring = population[:2]

    for i in range(0, len(population) - 1, 2):
        if random.random() <= 0.8:
            offspring.append(crossover(population[i], population[i+1]))
            offspring.append(crossover(population[i+1], population[i]))

    for chromosome in population:
        if random.random() <= 0.05:
            offspring.append(mutation(chromosome))

    while(len(offspring) < 4):
        offspring.append(str(generateChromosome()))

    return offspring

initial_population = generatePopulation(4)
threshold = 15.999

for i in range(10000):
    mating_pool = selection(initial_population)
    temp_population = offspingGenerator(mating_pool)
    temp_ranked_population = [(fitness(decode(chromosome)), chromosome) for chromosome in temp_population]
    temp_ranked_population.sort(reverse = True)
    new_population = [chromosome[1] for chromosome in temp_ranked_population][:4]

    print(f"Generation {i} best solution ---> {new_population[0]}")

    if fitness(decode(new_population[0])) >= threshold:
        print(f"The best solution is ---> {new_population[0]} and original value {decode(new_population[0])}")
        break

    initial_population = new_population
```

generateChromosome(): This function generates a random binary chromosome of length 8 (e.g., '01011010').

generatePopulation(size): This function generates a population of binary chromosomes of the specified size.

fitness(x): This function calculates the fitness of a chromosome using a simple quadratic fitness function: x*(8-x).

decode(x): This function decodes a binary chromosome into its decimal representation by interpreting it as an 8-bit binary fraction and converting it to the decimal range [0, 8].

selection(population): This function performs a selection process.

crossover(chromosome1, chromosome2): This function performs a single-point crossover between two chromosomes.

mutation(chromosome): This function performs bit-flip mutation on a chromosome.

offspingGenerator(population): This function generates offspring for the next generation by applying crossover and mutation to the selected individuals from the previous generation.

The goal of the algorithm is to find a chromosome whose fitness value (using the fitness(decode()) function) is greater than or equal to the threshold value (set to 15.999). When the best solution in a generation surpasses this threshold, the algorithm will terminate and print the solution.

**The problem is in my solution space I'm getting binary string of 7bits where it should be of 8bits.**
Help me finding the issue.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).